# Len function not giving correct value

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulty getting the Len() function to give a correct length of the number.

The section of code that Is having Difficulty is here:

```
Spec = Len(Range("J8")) - x
intermit = Range("I8") - Range("J8")
Low = Len(intermit)

MsgBox "Lower Spec: " & intermit & " Length: " & Low

intermit = Range("I8") + Range("J8")
High = Len(WorksheetFunction.Text(intermit, 0))
MsgBox "Upper Spec: " & intermit & " Length: " & High
```

Range("I8") = 0.0140

Range("J8") = 0.0002

The message boxes are supposed to display the following:

Lower Spec: 0.0138 Length: 6

Upper Spec: 0.0142 Length: 6

However they are displaying:

Lower Spec: 0.0138 Length: 8

Upper Spec: 0.0142 Length: 8

I tried converting the intermit variable to text but then it would return as 0. I do not know where the extra 2 characters that the function is counting is comming from.

Comment: Is it possible the values displayed in your cells are not the *actual* values held in the cells?  Cell formatting can make them different...

Comment: If I copy those values into `I8` and `J8`, the output is : `"Lower Spec: 0.0138 Length: 6"`, and `"Upper Spec: 0.0142 Length: 1"`...

Comment: There's more to the problem than what you're showing - I cannot reproduce the `8` output with the provided code.

Comment: *and numeric inputs

Comment: @TimWilliams The cells are formatted as general. I did a temp. message box displaying the number and length and it shows to be correct. (0.014 and 5)

Comment: @Carlos Are the values in your cells just typed in?  Or are they the results of formulas?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `WorksheetFunction.Text` to convert a `Variant/Double` to a `String`; the correct format string for it would have been `"@"`, not `0` - but you don't need to involve worksheet functions, the VBA standard library already provides a `VBA.Conversion` module that gives you a bunch of conversion functions, including `CStr`.

But, the `Len` function lives in the `VBA.Strings` module, which suggests that the string conversion would be implicit anyway - doesn't hurt to make that conversion explicit using an appropriate conversion function, especially given we're dealing with what appears to be undeclared variables, that would be `Variant/Double` at run-time, assuming the cell values are actually numeric values.

I cannot reproduce the problem with the provided code and values. This works for me:

```
Dim intermitLow As Double
intermitLow = Sheet2.Range("I8").Value - Sheet2.Range("J8").Value
Debug.Print intermitLow, Len(CStr(intermitLow))

Dim intermitHigh As Double
intermitHigh = Sheet2.Range("I8").Value + Sheet2.Range("J8").Value
Debug.Print intermitHigh, Len(CStr(intermitHigh))
```

Output with I8=0.014 (that non-significant trailing zero in the OP is worrying) and J8=0.0002:

```
 0.0138        6 
 0.0142        6
```

Note that I'm explicitly qualifying the `Range` member calls with a proper `Worksheet` object, here `Sheet2` (see [CodeName: Sheet1](http://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/?p=7384) for everything you need to know about worksheet code names). If your code is written in a standard module, then unqualified `Range` calls are [implicit `ActiveSheet` references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference), i.e. it's referring to *whatever worksheet happens to be active at the time*, which makes the code more frail than it needs to be - although, it doesn't appear to be the problem here, since we're working with the expected values.

Consider only reading the cell values once - no need to hit the worksheet again every time:

```
Dim value1 As Double 'todo use a meaningful name
'note: possible type mismatch on assignment depending on the data type of .Value
value1 = Sheet2.Range("I8").Value

Dim value2 As Double 'todo use a meaningful name
'note: possible type mismatch on assignment depending on the data type of .Value
value2 = Sheet2.Range("J8").Value

Dim intermitLow As Double
intermitLow = value1 - value2
Debug.Print intermitLow, Len(CStr(intermitLow))

Dim intermitHigh As Double
intermitHigh = value1 + value2
Debug.Print intermitHigh, Len(CStr(intermitHigh))
```

Avoid reusing variables/identifiers for different purposes within a procedure scope, and always declare all variables (have `Option Explicit` at the top of every module *forcing you* to do it).